# How can I compare two Arrays and detect if the values are incorrect or missing?

Tags: php, arrays

I have to arrays I would like to compare:
`$original` and `$duplicate`.

for example here is my original file:

```
  print_r($original);

  Array ( [0] => cat423 [1] => dog456 [2] => horse872 [3] => duck082 )
```

and here is my duplicate:

```
  print_r($dublicate);

  Array ( [0] => cat423 [1] => dug356 )
```

I compare them with `array_diff`:

```
$result = array_diff($original, $dublicate);
```

My result:

```
Array ( [1] => dog456 [2] => horse872 [3] => duck082 )
```

So far so good, but I need to make a difference between the values which are incorrect and the values which are completely missing. Is this possible?

Comment: Please see the tutorial http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Let me know that what is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is something like: Incorrect Values: `Array ( [1] => dog456 )`, Missing Values: `Array ( [2] => horse872 [3] => duck082 )`

Answer (score 1):

A way would be to crawl the entire `original` array, afterwards you will have two arrays, `missings` and `duplicates`.

```
$original = array("cat423", "dog456", "horse872", "duck082");
$duplicate = array("cat423", "dug356");

$missings = $duplicates = array();
foreach ($original as $val) {
    if (in_array($val, $duplicate))
        $duplicates[] = $val;
    else
        $missings[] = $val;
}
```

If you need the keys as well, you would have to alter the foreach loop like so:

```
foreach ($original as $key=>$val) {
    if (in_array($val, $duplicate))
        $duplicates[] = array("key" => $key, "value" => $val);
    else
        $missings[] = array("key" => $key, "value" => $val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [in_array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp) function

```
$original = array("cat423", "dog456", "horse872", "duck082");
$duplicate = array("cat423", "dug356");


foreach ($original as $item) {

    if(in_array($item, $duplicate))
    {
        $dup[] = $item;
    }        
    else
    {
        $miss[] = $item;
    }      
}
print_r($miss); #Array ( [0] => dog456 [1] => horse872 [2] => duck082 )
print_r($dup); #Array ( [0] => cat423 )
```

[Working Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/32qj-hecf)

Comment: See my answer before :-)